# Java chronicle throwing IllegalStateExecption at high number of messages

Tags: java, illegalstateexception, chronicle, chronicle-queue

When the number of messages to write are high, getting `IllegalStateException` after some time. Here is the code:

```
    chronicle = ChronicleQueueBuilder.indexed(basePrefix).build();
```

loop begin

```
    {
      appender = chronicle.createAppender();
      appender.startExcerpt();
      appender.writeObject(message);
      appender.finish();
    }
```

loop end

```
    chronicle.close();
```

java chronicle 3.6.2 is the version with java 1.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common reason for this error in Indexed Chronicle was that it was a single threaded writer.  You need to ensure you only have one thread writing to this, possibly with locking if needed.

You should be able to create just one Appender, ever and lock on this object or the queue itself (if you are using multiple threads)

Chronicle Queue v4+ doesn't have this limitation and supports any number of threads with a single file per cycle.

Comment: I am testing with synchronized block only for writing the Excerpts when observed the illegalStateException under high load.

Comment: @chappalprasad can you include the stack trace in the question?

Comment: synchronization within a framework was the issue, its working fine.  Thanks